# Is nifedipine a weak base or weak acid?

Tags: acid-base

I was wondering whether someone could explain me if nifedipine is a weak base or a weak acid. 
I barely can find any information about nifedipine's physicochemical properties in studies, however some suggested that it is a weak acid. If it is a weak acid, which hydrogen atom is dissociable and what would the pKa of that group be?

Thanks in advanced.

Nifedipine's structure, as shown on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nifedipine):

[image: Nifedipine]

Comment: [Here](http://www.drugbank.ca/drugs/DB01115) is a reference which states that the "strongest basic" pKa = 5.33. As for which proton, I'm not sure.

Comment: @ToddMinehardt perhaps the H atom at position 4 of the 1,4-dihydropyridine.

Comment: My guess is still the N-hydrogen. However a $pK_a$ of 4 is more acidic than I would expect, e.g. in comparison with phtalimide. But there may be higher order effects that affect the acidity.

Answer (score 2):

Nifedipine is a weak acid.

- [$pK_b = 10.07$](http://www.chemicalbook.com/ProductMSDSDetailCB6260129_EN.htm)
- [$pK_a = 3.93$](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2778603/)
- [$pK_a = 4.3$](https://books.google.de/books?id=6T0rTJ6N2dwC&pg=PA288&lpg=PA288&dq=nifedipine%20pka&source=bl&ots=j6SP_0IuPl&sig=O0RKEUqDQxfGTgpN-8Hw1BSG-mE&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjd_ODZ-9nMAhXBlCwKHdt_DhYQ6AEIJzAF#v=onepage&q=nifedipine%20pka&f=false)

Comment: Removed the statement that the N-hydrogen might be the acidic one.

Answer (score -1):

My *speculation* is a bit related to the answer provided by @aventurin.  In absence of experimental evidence to support this, I think in a first step the proton in (then) *para*-postion to the nitrogen is abstracted:

[image]

leading to a protonated, pyridinium specis, then in equilibrium to the non-protonated form.  This may be favourable by thecreation of an aromatic system.  Again, provided as a *speculation* including the notice that the initial deprotonation might be irreversible.

Comment: The abstraction of a proton in the first step would result in a nifedipine anion.

Comment: Your image shows a 3-nitrophenyl compound; however, nifedipine is a 2-nitrophenyl compound.

Comment: That nitrogen has a lone pair, your proposed "deprotonation" would lead to a nitrogen with 10 electrons around it (and as aventurin points out it should be negatively charged not positively). Your reaction is in fact a dehydrogenation and the intermediate results from a loss of hydride, not a deprotonation.